# TypeError: Cannot read property 'time' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have type error. My variable creating this error while running with node.js. My variable is below. How can I describe my variable correctly ?

```
let allDevices = {
        1: {
            time: []
        },
        2: {
            time: []
        },
        3: {
            time: []
        }
}
```

Comment: what gets held in time array? timestamps?

Comment: please show how you are accessing the array

Comment: `allDevices[1].time.push("data")` I use like this my variable. @JoshStevens @germanio

Comment: If you're accessing it that way but still getting an undefined error, it's probably an asynchronous code problem where you're trying to access the data before allDevices is instantiated.

Comment: I solved my problem. I was using wrong my variable. like `allDevices[y].time.substring(0, 5)`. I was need to use like `allDevices[1].time[2].substring(0, 5)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're trying `allDevices.1.time` to get the above error message.  With numeric object keys, you'd need to reference the numbered object keys using `[]` instead of `.` notation:

```js
let allDevices = {
  1: {
    time: []
  },
  2: {
    time: []
  },
  3: {
    time: []
  }
}

console.log(allDevices[1].time) // or allDevices['1'].time
```

You probably don't want that object structure, though; allDevices should probably just be an array, so you don't need to manage the index numbers manually.  You'd access it the same way (but note that arrays are zero-indexed):

```js
let allDevices = [
  {
    time: []
  },
  {
    time: []
  },
  {
    time: []
  }
]

console.log(allDevices[0].time) // here, allDevices['1'] would not work; the index must be a number
```

If you are using the bracket notation already but still getting 'undefined' errors, check to make sure the data exists before you try accessing it; if allDevices is set up by something asynchronous you'll need to wait until that async call returns.

Comment: I already use like this. But I get type error.

Comment: see the last paragraph of the answer

Comment: I solved my problem. I was using wrong my variable. like `allDevices[y].time.substring(0, 5)`. I was need to use like `allDevices[1].time[2].substring(0, 5)`